Building an Open Pretrained Transformer from Scratch with NumPy
I tried to convert the OPT written by huggingface into one written with NumPy, but the results turned out to be very strange, and I don't know what to do.
My code :
import numpy as np

def gelu(x):
    return x * (x > 0)
    # return 0.5 * x * (1 + np.tanh(np.sqrt(2 / np.pi) * (x + 0.044715 * x**3)))

def softmax(x):
    exp_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
    return exp_x / np.sum(exp_x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

def layer_norm(x, weight, bias, eps: float = 1e-5):
    mean = np.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    variance = np.var(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    x = (x - mean) / np.sqrt(variance + eps)  # normalize x to have mean=0 and var=1 over last axis
    return weight * x + bias  # scale and offset with gamma/beta params

def linear(x, weight, bias):  # [m, in], [in, out], [out] -> [m, out]
    return x @ weight + bias

def ffn(x, f1, f2):  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]
    # project up
    a = gelu(linear(x, f1["weight"].T, f1["bias"]))  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, 4*n_embd]

    # project back down
    x = linear(a, f2["weight"].T, f2["bias"])  # [n_seq, 4*n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]

    return x


def attention(q, k, v, mask):  # [n_q, d_k], [n_k, d_k], [n_k, d_v], [n_q, n_k] -> [n_q, d_v]
    return softmax(q @ k.T / np.sqrt(q.shape[-1]) + mask) @ v

def mha(x, k_proj, v_proj, q_proj, out_proj, n_head):  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]
    # qkv projection
    k = linear(x, **k_proj)
    q = linear(x, **q_proj)
    v = linear(x, **v_proj)
      # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, 3*n_embd]
    qkv = np.stack((q,k,v))

    qkv_heads = list(map(lambda x: np.split(x, n_head, axis=-1), qkv))
    # causal mask to hide future inputs from being attended to
    causal_mask = (1 - np.tri(x.shape[0], dtype=x.dtype)) * -1e10  # [n_seq, n_seq]

    # perform attention over each head
    out_heads = [attention(q, k, v, causal_mask) for q, k, v in zip(*qkv_heads)]
    
    # merge heads
    x = np.hstack(out_heads)  # [n_head, n_seq, n_embd/n_head] -> [n_seq, n_embd]

    # out projection
    x = linear(x, **out_proj)  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]

    return x

def transformer_block(x, fc1, fc2, self_attn, self_attn_layer_norm, final_layer_norm, n_head):  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]
    # multi-head causal self attention
    # x = x + mha(layer_norm(x, **ln_1), **attn, n_head=n_head)  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]
    x = x + mha(layer_norm(x, **self_attn_layer_norm), **self_attn, n_head=n_head)
    # x = x + layer_norm(mha(x, **self_attn, n_head=n_head), **self_attn_layer_norm)
    # position-wise feed forward network
    x = x + ffn(layer_norm(x, **final_layer_norm), fc1, fc2)  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]
    # x = x + layer_norm(ffn(x, fc1, fc2), **final_layer_norm)

    return x


def opt(inputs, embed_tokens, embed_positions, blocks, final_layer_norm, lm_head, n_head):  # [n_seq] -> [n_seq, n_vocab]
    # token + positional embeddings
    # print(embed_tokens["weight"][inputs])
    # print(embed_positions["weight"][range(len(inputs))])
    x = embed_tokens["weight"][inputs] + embed_positions["weight"][range(len(inputs))]  # [n_seq] -> [n_seq, n_embd]
    # forward pass through n_layer transformer blocks
    for block in blocks:
        x = transformer_block(x, **block, n_head=n_head)  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]

    # projection to vocab
    x = layer_norm(x, **final_layer_norm)  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_embd]
    return x @ lm_head["weight"].T  # [n_seq, n_embd] -> [n_seq, n_vocab]


def generate(inputs, params, n_head, n_tokens_to_generate):
    from tqdm import tqdm

    for _ in tqdm(range(n_tokens_to_generate), "generating"):  # auto-regressive decode loop
        logits = opt(inputs, **params, n_head=n_head)  # model forward pass
        next_id = np.argmax(logits[-1])  # greedy sampling
        inputs.append(int(next_id))  # append prediction to input

    return inputs[len(inputs) - n_tokens_to_generate :]  # only return generated ids

def main(prompt: str, n_tokens_to_generate: int = 2, model_size: str = "124M", models_dir: str = "models"):
    from utils2 import load_encoder_hparams_and_params
    
    from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer

    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/opt-125m")
    model_inputs = tokenizer([prompt], return_tensors="pt")
    # load encoder, hparams, and params from the released open-ai gpt-2 files
    encoder, hparams, params = load_encoder_hparams_and_params(model_size, models_dir)
    input_ids = model_inputs['input_ids'].detach().cpu().numpy()
    input_ids =input_ids.reshape(-1)
    input_ids =input_ids.tolist()
    # print(input_ids.shape)
    # encode the input string using the BPE tokenizer
    # input_ids = encoder.encode(prompt)
    # print(input_ids)
    # make sure we are not surpassing the max sequence length of our model
    assert len(input_ids) + n_tokens_to_generate < hparams["n_ctx"]
    # print(params)
    # generate output ids
    output_ids = generate(input_ids, params, hparams["n_head"], n_tokens_to_generate)
    print(output_ids)
    # decode the ids back into a string
    tokenizer.batch_decode(output_ids)[0]

    return tokenizer.batch_decode(output_ids)[0]

main("Amy is a big fan of")


convert opt-125m pytorch.bin to npy file
import torch

checkpoint = torch.load("opt_pytorch_model.bin")

def set_in_nested_dict(d, keys, val):
    if not keys:
        return val
    if keys[0] not in d:
        d[keys[0]] = {}
    d[keys[0]] = set_in_nested_dict(d[keys[0]], keys[1:], val)
    return d

params = {"blocks": [{} for _ in range(12)]}

for name in checkpoint:
    np_arr = checkpoint[name].detach().cpu().numpy()
    np_arr =np.squeeze(np_arr)
    if name.startswith("model.decoder.layers"):
        
        parts = name.split(".")
        layer_idx = int(parts[3])
        sub_name = ".".join(parts[4:])
        # print(sub_name)
        set_in_nested_dict(params["blocks"][layer_idx], sub_name.split("."), np_arr)
    elif name.startswith("model.decoder."):
        name = name[len("model.decoder."):]
        # print(name)
        set_in_nested_dict(params, name.split("."), np_arr)
    else:
        set_in_nested_dict(params, name.split("."), np_arr)

np.save("params.npy", params)``




utils2.py ↓
import json
import os
import re

import numpy as np
import requests
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm

from encoder import get_encoder



def load_encoder_hparams_and_params(model_size, models_dir):
    assert model_size in ["124M", "355M", "774M", "1558M"]

    model_dir = os.path.join(models_dir, model_size)
    

    encoder = get_encoder(model_size, models_dir)
    hparams = json.load(open(os.path.join(model_dir, "hparams.json")))
    # params = load_gpt2_params_from_tf_ckpt(tf_ckpt_path, hparams)
    params =np.load("params.npy", allow_pickle=True)[()]
    # print((params))

    return encoder, hparams, params`


reference:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.46.2/src/transformers/models/opt/modeling_opt.py#L992
https://github.com/jaymody/picoGPT/blob/main/gpt2.py
https://huggingface.co/facebook/opt-125m/tree/main
When I input the prompt: 'Amy is the big fan of', the output from HuggingFace is 'Amy is the big fan of the show', but the output from my NumPy version is '-'. I hope my NumPy version can produce the correct output.
